# Streamline Jest stdio / user input in CLI

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, jestjs, stdio

When using Jest in CLI, any output to stdio (not `console.log()`) is jammed between the "RUNS" output and the top of the prompt. see the following example:

[image: Weird prompt]

Which looks both out of place and broken (and confuses the user. edit for clarity: by "user" I mean other developers running this test). I'm aware that I could probably fix this with some stdio hack that involves moving the cursor and such, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Currently using https://github.com/terkelg/prompts for the prompt itself.

Comment: Jest has some serious issues in the way it deals with stdio/stderr. In fact it's eating console.log outputs in some cases. You might try `--runInBand` to see if that changes things. `--verbose false` (or `true` even) is known to have some effect on where/when/how things are logged